# WindowProc Event system not responding in real-time

Tags: c, windows, winapi, events, graphics

I have made this event system to abstract platform code (currently win32 api). I built a simple event queueing system to dispatch the system messages, but my events aren't responding in real time. My events seem to pile up and get all pushed at once when I am done.

example **printing size**: when resizing by dragging the window border, the Quest_Log function doesn't print until I am done resize, only then it will print all the positions it should've printed while resizing.

```c
#include "Quest.h"

int main(void) {
    if(Quest_Init(QUEST_SUBSYSTEM_VIDEO) > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    Quest_Window *window = Quest_CreateWindow("Example", 100, 100, 640, 480, QUEST_WINDOW_DEFAULT);
    if(window == NULL) {
        return 2;
    }
    bool running = true;
    while(running) {
        Quest_Event event;
        while(Quest_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case QUEST_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
                case QUEST_WINDOW_RESIZING:
                    Quest_Log("Window resizing: %d;%d\n", event.window.width, event.window.height);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    Quest_DestroyWindow(window);
    Quest_Shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

and here is how I am polling and pushing events:

```c
#define QUEST_MAX_EVENTS 0xffffui16

static Quest_Event  sQueue[QUEST_MAX_EVENTS] = {0};
static unsigned int Qsize = 0;

bool Quest_PollEvent(Quest_Event *event) {
    MSG  msg;
    bool result = false;
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            event->type = QUEST_QUIT;
            result = true;
            return result;
        } else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    if(Qsize > 0) {
        *event = sQueue[0];
        {
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Qsize - 1; i++) {
                sQueue[i] = sQueue[i + 1];
            }
            --Qsize;
        }
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}

void Quest_PushEvent(const Quest_Event *event) {
    if(Qsize < sizeof(sQueue) / sizeof(sQueue[0])) {
        sQueue[Qsize++] = *event;
    }
}
```

Basically this is the windowproc

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
    Quest_Event event;
    memset(&event, 0x0000, sizeof(Quest_Event));
    switch(uMsg) {
    // other messages
        case WM_SIZING: {
            switch(wParam) {
                case SIZE_MAXIMIZED:
                    event.type = QUEST_WINDOW_MAXIMIZE;
                    break;
                case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
                    event.type = QUEST_WINDOW_MINIMIZE;
                    break;
                case SIZE_RESTORED:
                    event.type = QUEST_WINDOW_RESIZE;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            event.window.width = LOWORD(lParam);
            event.window.height = HIWORD(lParam);
        } break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    Quest_PushEvent(&e);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Comment: [`WM_SIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size) is not sent until the window has *finished* being resized. You might be looking for [`WM_SIZING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-sizing) instead, which is sent *while* the window is in the process of being resized.

Comment: Both suggestion don't change the outcome.

Comment: Also, inside of `Quest_PollEvent()`, `while(Qsize > 0)` should be `if(Qsize > 0)` instead, since you are processing only 1 queued event at a time. And, `while(PeekMessage(...) > 0)` should probably be `if(PeekMessage(...) > 0)` as well. Think of when a timer is running, for example. If you use `while(PeekMesssage())`, you are handling multiple window messages at a time, and you might lag behind/never process your queued events in a timely manner.

Comment: There is only 1 `WM_SIZE` message per resize operation. But you claim there should be multiple positions printed. Where are those extra events actually coming from? Please provide a [mcve] that shows everything you are doing/seeing.

Comment: When I run it in C++ using std::thread to join the main loop to while(GetMessage) it prints continuously as I am resizing. but with this method using PeekMessage in the main loop in keeps the strings it should've printed until I finish resizing and then it prints everything to the console. Even WM_SIZING doesn't print while resizing.

Comment: There is no difference to message handling when using `GetMessage()` versus `PeekMessage()`, other than the former waits for a new message and the latter doesn't. However, the code you have shown is not thread-safe, and message loops must be handled per-thread. Does your worker thread run its own poll loop? Or are you expecting only the main thread to do the polling? Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The code I posted is all there is, my main function runs the loop and there is no thread safety handling. And to be quite honest, I only have been programming for 2-3 months now, so I don't even know how threads and mutex work. :/

Comment: This approach is as broken as Qt's. Once you go the *"let's just replay messages"* route, all hell breaks loose. There is no recovering from there. You'll need a different approach that doesn't rely on replaying messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated the code snippets to be clearer. there isn't much more to the event system than that other than the event types enum declaration and the event struct.

Comment: @IInspectable Any suggesions please?

Comment: You are pushing an event into your queue for *every* window message that is received. That is going to slow down your queue processing considerably, as you are going to encounter a LOT of empty events before you reach your size event. For instance, every `WM_PAINT` message to going to push an event into the queue, and windows paint themselves very often.

Comment: And how should I be doing it?

Comment: Are they native winAPIs? I don't know about "Quest".

Comment: Quest is the name I gave to the framework. for example Quest_Init, for now only calls AllocConsole. the rest of the code Create window just registers the window class and creates the HWND and shows it. and the rest is in the post

Comment: *"Any suggesions please?"* - Spend a decade trying. Framework code, by a wide margin, is the most difficult code you'll ever write. If you need inspiration, look into MFC, ATL, and WTL.

Comment: @IInspectable so it's trial and error until I learn how to do it properly. Well, I am in for a journey.